# Struts2 UI textarea tag adding "class" attribute fills it self with "class java.util.HashMap" value

Tags: struts2

This is just a why is something weird happening question.

I made a mistake and was supposed to use "cssClass" but typed "class" instead. However "class" is not defined as a property of the textarea tag so I expected the behaviour to be the same as the cssClass value (a non defined property should be rendered as is, and it does render the property but has a strange value and that value does not seem to be alterable. Any value I feed it is ignored and defaults to the class which backs the tag).

For instance if I define a "turkey" value I would expect a turkey value to be rendered in html and it is as we can see in the following example.

Here is what I used on the JSP:

```
<s:textarea turkey="" class="" name="qualLine.description" value="%{description}"/>
```

Here is what was rendered:

```
<textarea name="qualLine.description" cols="" rows="" id="cows" class="class java.util.HashMap" turkey="">test</textarea>
```

My question isn't what should I do, because I *should* have used cssClass instead of class, my question is: *Is* this expected and why?

Comment: is it occurring everywhere in your application or just on this particular page, problem seems a bit strange

Comment: I check this and it happens with `<s:password>`, `<s:label>`, `<s:textfield>` too ...

Comment: @Pigueiras: you mean to say it is showing class as `java.util.HashMap`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Yes, I do.

Comment: @Pigueiras: i believe it is coming due to the declaration of `dynamicAttributes` which is actually `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext
Interface DynamicAttributes`. Have a look at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.6/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ui/AbstractUITag.java#AbstractUITag and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes.html

Comment: I don't find creating custom Struts2 tags very easy and as I spent a few minutes looking into the issue I remember why inheritance isn't always your friend. You need to examine a lot of classes up the chain to understand how one tag works.  I'm still not sure where the issue is: I think evaluateParams() in org.struts2.components.UIBean could play a part, but... I just don't know.

Comment: I'm looking for a logical explanation referencing the code base.

Comment: which version of struts2 are you using, how is your html page defined, html5 or html4, and which one, are you using some kind of template engine like freemaker or velocity, etc..

Comment: and which form template are you using, `simple`, `xhtml` or `...`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 It is not an issue of the template. You can try for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is related to the Freemarker TemplateModel being used?

In the `dynamic-attributes.ftl`, which is included from the `textarea.ftl` to resolve the dynamic attributes, the attribute value is first evaluated against the ValueStack using a `StrutsUtil.translateVariables` instance, which just uses a static call to the `TestParseUtil.translateVariables`.  But when that doesn't evaluate to anything (null or void), it then reverts to the attribute name - class.

This value, "class", is then evaluated as a Freemarker expression - `${class}` - in the dynamic-attributes.ftl.

The StrutsUtil is placed in the Freemarker template model from the `FreemarkerManager` which calls the `ContextUtil` to retrieve a map of Struts2 objects to place into the template model.  This map that is placed in the TemplateModel is a HashMap (perhaps the culprit map?).

So, this is obviously not a complete answer, so I don't expect the "answer" to be accepted, but it was too much to place in a comment and it may help to shed some light.  If I have time later in the week, I may pull down the Struts2 source and play with it to find the real answer.  But more likely, I won't take the time!

Interesting question for sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because every Java Object has a method `getClass()`, which returns the runtime class of an object, in your case `java.util.HashMap`. This way, although `class` is not defined for the textearea tag, it is defined for the [TextareaTag](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/apidocs/org/apache/struts/taglib/html/TextareaTag.html) class, which is the class that implements the textarea behaviour. This will happen with every tag in your jsps, as all of them are implemented with a Java class in the end.

That's why (I guess) the Struts team used `cssClass` propery intead of just using `class`.

Comment: I'll accept an answer which provides the implementation of the  behaviour, what was pointed at (Tag) was an interface.

Comment: You're right, Tag is an Interface (my bad). I have edited the answer with the implementation of the textarea, which of course implements the `Tag` interface.

Comment: This still does not address the issue, as Umesh has pointed out tags which handle dynamic attributes need to implement the DynamicAttributes interface. The setDynamicAttribute method is called for each such attribute "class" being no exception. The tag class is not treated as a simple bean with access from the outside world, so somewhere down this path struts2 is deciding to do something magical with the "class" attribute. I mentioned in an earlier comment the evaluateParams method which has specific handling for certain attributes but not class. It might be an issue during retrieval...

Comment: What ever the case I can think of no reason class should have this behavior. Frankly it is a little weird that we need to use cssClass at all if you think about it. If there is some strange purpose for this undocumented feature it should be given another name allowing us to use "class" as we would expect and reduce the struts2 documentation slightly.

Answer (score 0):

use

> cssClass="input-sm"

instead of

> class="input-sm"

when you use struts input like

```
<s:textfield cssClass=input-sm id="a" key="" name="" placeholder="Required"/>
```

Comment: I think if you re-read the question you'll see that the question you'll see that I'm interested in the effect of using the "class" attribute and that I'm aware of the correct use of "cssClass"